# PuTTY X11 proxy: wrong authorisation protocol attempted

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, putty

I am trying to connect to an Ubuntu server to work on Qt-creator. Before everything goes wrong, I followed [this](http://www.math.umn.edu/systems_guide/putty_xwin32.html) tutorial. I downloaded putty and Xming and everything was working just fine.

then, suddenly, while working on Qt-creator I couldn't save any changes. So, I closed Qt-creator and restart the putty session. it asked me about username and password (as usual) then after log-in into the server and when I tried to run Qt-creator (as usual) the following message appears:

```
PuTTY X11 proxy: wrong authorisation protocol attempted
Can't open display: localhost:10.0
```

so, I tried to resolve the problem using two approaches found in the internet:

the first one is by getting the `dpyname protoname hexkey` using:

```
xauth list
```

which should return the key which is then could be added using:

```
xauth add
```

However, it didn't work as the `xauth list` command returned nothing.

the second solution was to go to:

```
./etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

open the file: sshd_config and edit the `ForwardX11Trusted` line to read `yes`, and If no such line exists, add it in.

```
ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

then restart the ssh server and it should work.

However, it didn't work either. I could not open the file `sshd_config` using `xdg-open` or `gedit` and the same message appears again.

so why is this happening and what is the solution for it ?

Comment: The good news is: I am now able to open the file: `sshd_config` using `sudo nano` command and add the line: `ForwardX11Trusted yes`.. the bad news is: after the "adding step" the problem still exists !!!

Comment: What is the full command when you use ``xauth add``?

Comment: `ForwardX11Trusted` is an option for the OpenSSH client,, not for the server. Adding it might prevent `sshd` from starting, depending on the version.

Answer (score 19):

While logged in as su, after a few "PuTTY X11 proxy: wrong authorisation protocol attempted" -type errors, I realized it was an authentication problem. Then I remembered to copy the .Xauthority file from my own profile /home directory to /root. Problem solved!

Comment: This looks like answer to a different problem (although with the same symptoms).

Comment: This worked for Raspbian Jessie on RaspberryPi

Comment: This also worked for me on RPI. From PuTTy on Win10 simple `leafpad` worked fine, but `sudo leafpad` has thrown error in description above. Copying `.Xauthority` worked flawlessly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: ok for the authorization problem... but still gives me "Cannot open display:"... ?any ideas

Comment: Works for `sudo` commands too. First use `xauth list` and make sure your current non-root user is listed, and then copy your `~/.Xauthority` to `/root/`.

Answer (score 3):

## Solved.

I got it solved using a mixture of the two mentioned above.

#### 1. I added the following line to '/etc/ssh/sshd_config'

```
ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

#### 2. I installed xauth using

```
sudo apt-get install xauth
```

`xauth list` was empty for me before restart. It was, however, populated after the restart. I did `xauth list` after I tested it with putty.

Then I restarted ssh and it worked. Yay!

Note: What I actually did was **restart my Raspberry Pi**

Comment: ForwardX11Trusted is not a valid option for sshd_config.  It is a client parameter, not a server daemon parameter

Comment: I'd done this quite some time ago. Don't know now.

Comment: Do **NOT** add `ForwardX11Trusted yes` to your `sshd_config` as it will probably cause your ssh server to fail after being rebooted.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem on a server at work because the home folder was out of disk space. After login, it couldn't write the Xauthority file and... couldn't forward.

Freeing up space resolved the issue.

I would imagine you would have a similar problem if home folder or .Xauthority permissions were set improperly so you did not have write access.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I noticed I could open the Display with root, but I was doing a su - grid, and this user grid was the one with the problem,

the solution was to close this session, and open a new session directly with grid, and it worked, something about doing the su - grid was failing...

Answer (score 1):

The insight regarding the **.Xauthority** file is correct, but the approach of overwriting another user's file should give one pause.  Consider the conflict created if two hypothetical users Alice and Bob both attempted to overwrite **~root/.Xauthority** while logged in simultaneously.  The user also needs to remember to do the rude copy whenever their personal copy is updated and would be blocked if **~root/.Xauthority** could not be created or updated due to unrelated issues such as a read-only filesystem mount or complete lack of disk space.

The intent of the proposed solution can be honored by exploiting the **XAUTHORITY** environment variable, which could be conveniently set during login by the user's appropriate login-only script.  This is illustrated by the **.bash_profile** fragment below:

```
if test -n "${DISPLAY}"
then
    XAUTHORITY=`LANG=C xauth info | awk '{ print $NF; exit; }'`
    export XAUTHORITY
fi
```

Note that the `LANG=C` prefix to the `xauth` invocation protects against unexpected results in locales with right-to-left reading order.

This approach has the benefits of being automatic, does not require write permission to files under **~root** and prevents multiple simultaneous users from interfering with each other.

Note that there can be a difference in behavior between obtaining privileges via `sudo` and becoming **root** (or a different user) via `su`. On some systems, the **pam_xauth** module is enabled in **/etc/pam.d/su**, which performs automatic import of the session key and creation of a temporary authority file that will be pointed to by the **XAUTHORITY** environment variable.  On such systems, by default `su` yields a shell that can communicate with the X11 display (thanks to the magic of the **pam_xauth** module) while a command invoked using `sudo` would not.  The approach above does not interfere with the behavior of `su` on systems that have enabled the **pam_xauth** module and also, when the **pam_xauth** module is not enabled, allows `su` to work if the appropriate preserve environment argument is passed (e.g., `su -p`).  If you are unsure of your system's configuration, compare and contrast the output of:

```
sudo xauth info
```

vs.

```
su -c 'xauth info'
```

when **XAUTHORITY** is not set and then set appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on a server.
The reason was that user got the wrong number of display (DISPLAY=localhost:10.0).
When user connects to the server via SSH (as user called test1) he gets DISPLAY=localhost:11.0.
When he connects as another user, and then becomes user (test1), he gets wrong number of display (DISPLAY=localhost:10.0).
When I set the rifght number of DISPLAY (DISPLAY=localhost:11.0) it works.

Answer (score 0):

check whether $DISPLAY variable is set, command: echo $DISPLAY
if the display variable is not set, run this command: export DISPLAY=:0.0

Comment: Did you notice that the user is working on a remote host (via PuTTY)?

Comment: May be I didn't understood your question clearly,  Yes, I do connect to the remote hosts by using the above. Where your seeing challenges here.

Comment: ```export DISPLAY=:0.0``` is used when the X server and the X client are on the same host.  Generally, if you login directly to computer A (possibly a laptop or a small desktop workstation) and then login remotely (PuTTY / ssh) to computer B (possibly a high-end machine with many CPUs and tons of RAM (and secondary storage; i.e., disk / SSD), but possibly headless), you want to run an X client on computer B but use the X server on computer A — so your answer would be inappropriate.  If you can touch the keyboard / mouse of computer B and see its screen, why not just login to it directly?