# How can I access my Ubuntu server GUIs from a local network Windows 11 PC?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-11

I tried to use X server as per my post:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1409289/error-no-display-environment-variable-specified-when-using-x-server

I was thinking about setting my DISPLAY env.var. to windowsuser@windowsPC:0.0 or something similar but have no idea how to do that.

I tried my luck with PuTTY and MobaXTerm but this error came:

[image]

Then tried all solutions from:

[PuTTY X11 proxy: wrong authorisation protocol attempted](https://superuser.com/questions/610084/putty-x11-proxy-wrong-authorisation-protocol-attempted)

but without success.

Attempt with root privileges:

[image]

Comment: You have all of this wrong.  In your other post `If I set DISPLAY to localhost 0.0, it says:` .. well of course it does!  "localhost" refers to the machine it is run on, not the machine you are shelling in from.  You already said that it was headless!  Where is the display supposed to go?  You told it to go back to the headless server!   Start here:  `export DISPLAY=<the_ip_only_of_the_comp_you_ran_ssh_from>:0.0` .. then try.  Read [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=understanding+loopback+address) to understand what localhost maps to.  Good Luck!! :)

Comment: Oh.. also, kill Xming but no, you are wrong.. YES, YOU NEED AN XSERVER.  I suggest a different one.  ***MobaXTerm*** will do a lot of the magic (setting up the DISPLAY variable and provide an x-server.  ***VxXsrv*** is also a very nice product.  The x-server is what receives the forwarded x11 commands and draws stuff.  Linux->Windows x11 won't work without one.  Windows 11 has some stuff built in that might fill this need.. but I am ignorant there.

Comment: , before your comment, I tried my luck with PuTTY. It gives the same error as with MobaXTerm. I will put it in the post.

Comment: PuTTY is an SSH client (like any other), doesn't auto-configure your DISPLAY variable and doesn't provide an x-server where MobaXTerm is sort of a one stop shop (ssh client + x-server).  I myself dont use it anymore because 90% of the time, my x-client is running under WSL and I don't need the ssh to and from.